# Python web scraping unstructured table

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to extract some information from a table which appears on a webpage, but the table is unstructured with row being header and column being content like this: (My apologies for not disclosing the webpage)

```
<table class="table-detail">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="noborder">General Information
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Full name</th>
                    <td>
                        James Smith
                    </td>
                    <th>Year of birth</th>
                    <td>1992</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <td>Male</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Place of birth</th>
                    <td>TTexas, USA</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <td>Texas, USA</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
```

At the moment, I am able to extract the table by using this script:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "example.com"

r = requests.get(url)
df_list = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = df_list[0]
df.head()

df.to_csv('myfile.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

And the table essentially looks like the following:

[image]

However, I am a little stuck with how to achieve this on Python. I cannot seem to get my head around to getting the data. The result I want is as below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to parse the HTML. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<table class="table-detail">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="noborder">General Information
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Full name</th>
                    <td>
                        James Smith
                    </td>
                    <th>Year of birth</th>
                    <td>1992</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <td>Male</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Place of birth</th>
                    <td>TTexas, USA</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <td>Texas, USA</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

row = {}
for h in soup.select('th:has(+td)'):
    row[h.text] = h.find_next('td').get_text(strip=True)

df = pd.DataFrame([row])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Full name Year of birth Gender Place of birth     Address
0  James Smith          1992   Male    TTexas, USA  Texas, USA
```

Comment: I've been trying hours to figure this out. Your code works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated it!